# Braintree form error: ncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one - Magento 2.1

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

We have Magento 2.1 installed and we are completing the integration with Braintree, everything seems to be working fine, however, on latest version of Chrome shows this error:

[image]

```
braintree-2.17.6.min.js:4 Uncaught TypeError: FormNapper requires an HTMLFormElement element or the id string of one.
```

I have contacted Braintree but they said their hosted forms doesn't have this issue and that is something in Magento.

Anyone had this issue?

Comment: Yes, I've posted this on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807955/uncaught-typeerror-formnapper-requires-an-htmlformelement-element-or-the-id-str) - did you solve this somehow?

Comment: Nope. Did you solve?

Comment: I got an answer that helped me. It was related to the way I injected the JavaScript code in my GWT application. not sure if this helps you but check it out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38807955/uncaught-typeerror-formnapper-requires-an-htmlformelement-element-or-the-id-str/38813017?noredirect=1#comment64996047_38813017